# laravel find() when return null blade file return error

Tags: php, laravel

I try to pass model to view.blade 
when model is not null , blade file run without bugs
but if model is null , blade file run bugs
this is my code

```
//StudentController code

public function viewstudent($id)
{
   $student = Student::find($id);
   $outputs = array($student);

   return view('student',['students'=>$outputs]);
}


//student.blade.php  code

<table id="myTable">

@foreach ($students as $student)    

<tr>
<td>{{$student->studentname}}</td>
<td>{{$student->studentlevel}}</td>
<td>{{$student->studentgender === 1 ?'Male':'Female'}}</td>
<td>{{$student->studentbirthdate}}</td>
<td>{{$student->studentnotes}}</td>
<td>{{$student->created_at}}</td>
<td>{{$student->updated_at}}</td>

</tr>
@endforeach

</table>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Also pay attention you're iterating over an array and you try to reach object properties with '->'.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it is an error because you're trying to access properties on a non-object.  Your array would have one element of `null`.

This is a bad design because if the student doesn't exist, you should not be returning the view to begin with.  You should be throwing some error, possibly a HTTP 404.

Luckily, Laravel makes this easy.  You can use `Student::findOrFail($id);` to throw an exception when the  student does not exist.

---

It seems strange to me that you're looping through students in your view when your controller is only returning one student.  If for some reason you don't want a 404, you could always run $outputs through array_filter to get rid of the null value, or just not add it to $outputs when it is null..